# Javascript - submit multiple forms on a page in new windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

So I have a page (which I visit as regular a user) containing lot of form tags looking like this:

```
<form style="display:none" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="kontroler.php" id="form_07206ee15b3bc3414cd3f7c130e01f3a" target="self"><input type="hidden" name="_action" value="actionx:dla_stud/rejestracja/brdg2/zarejestruj(rej_kod:WPA-P-13@12f14CW2;prz_kod:WPA-10.PZ-201cw;cdyd_kod:13@12f14Z;odczyt:0;callback:g_a5cf18cd)"><input type="hidden" name="csrftoken" value="2013-09-25-fe1c0bd16e51a7a7"></form>
```

I would like to "open" (submit) all of the forms moreless simultaneously, so that I have all of them open in new windows / tabs (by default they have `target='_self'`. I wrote this piece of Javascript, which I run from console (using Chrome Developer Tools):

```
//set target for all forms to new windows
$("form").each(function(index){ 
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank'); 
});

$("form").each(function(index){ 
    var timer = index*1000;
    self = $(this); 
    var t=setTimeout(function(){
            self.submit()
    },timer);
});
```

I already told Chrome accept popup windows from the page I am using. However the result I get is only one new window with one of the form "submitted". Why is that?

Comment: It's a closure issue, similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812941/javacript-increment-not-working)