# Javascript increment not working

Tags: javascript, html

Well I did not know what exactly would be a good title for this because it is a most peculiar situation or I'm abnormally dumb.

Here's what im trying to do.

Create a simple `<meter>` tag which is new in HTML5. The main issue is with my javascript. Im trying to increment the value of the meter tag gradually in my javascript. But somehow it doesn't work the way i want.

JavaScript.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    var a = document.getElementById("mtr1");
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(i);
        a.value = i;
    }, 250);
}
```

I'm trying to increase the value of the meter gradually every 250 ms.This doesn't happen. Instead the meter jumps straight to 10.

What interested me was the value of `i` that i got in the console. I got instances of `10`, instead of 1,2,3...10.

Why does this happen?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qh6gb/2/)

Comment: setTimeout is a deferred event, it does not run inline so your for loop will exit without the function ever running, then 10 seconds later it will increment a.

Comment: This question has already been answered many times here, search for javascript closure and scope.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Closures and setTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479604/javascript-closures-and-settimeout)

Comment: So many incorrect answers........

Comment: Yeah, maybe it is a duplicate. But not a very widely encountered problem. Judging by many incorrect answers i got i still think many ppl are unaware of this.

Comment: I would hope that people do not close this question mainly because of all the good answers it has generated. I have recieved at 4 different variations to solve this issue. So pls keep this alive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a JavaScript closures' classic. Here `i` is an actual reference to the variable, not its copy. After you've iterated through the loop it has the value of 10, that's why all log invocations write 10 to log.
This should work better:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    var a = document.getElementById("mtr1");
    setTimeout(function (i) {
        return function() {
            console.log(i);
            a.value = i;
        };
    }(i), 250 * i);
}
```

Here the most inner `i` is the `setTimeout`'s callback argument, not the variable which you've declared in the loop body.

Comment: I was just writing this.

Comment: @MarsOne you're welcome. take a look at my updated answer, I added corrected version of your code.

Comment: Tried it in a fiddle. Unfortunately, it doesnt work perfectly

Comment: Hm, it writes all values of `i`, from 1 to 10 to log, and sets the values of `i` to the meter. Could you tell me what didn't work as expected?

Comment: Yeah. But the delay doesnt happen after each atrrition. Check this to see what i expect http://jsfiddle.net/Qh6gb/11/

Comment: @MarsOne oh yeah, you're completely right! See corrected version.

Comment: I had to set different delays to all callbacks, not 250 to all of them.

Comment: Perfect... Totally fixed it

Comment: Glad to help you. :) @MarsOne, I personally recommend you to read 'JavaScript: The Good Parts' by Douglas CrockFord. It's small (150+ pages or so), and it's definitely worth reading, after reading it I can understand the beauty of plalx' solution.

Answer (score 7):

You should read more about closures in JavaScript. When a variable gets closed over, it's the same exact variable, not a copy. Since `setTimeout` is asynchronous, the whole loop finishes before any of the functions run, therefore the `i` variable will be `10` everywhere.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qh6gb/11/)

```
function incMtrAsync(max, delay, el) {
    if (el.value++ < max) {
        setTimeout(incMtrAsync.bind(null, max, delay, el), delay);
    }   
}

incMtrAsync(10, 250, document.getElementById("mtr1"));
```

The above implementation implements the loop using a recursive approach. Everytime `inMtrAsync` is called, it checks if the `value` of the meter reached the max value, and if not, registers another timeout with a callback to itself.

If you want to delay the initial increment as well, just wrap the first call in another timeout.

```
setTimeout(incMtrAsync.bind(null, 10, 250, document.getElementById("mtr1")), 250);
```

Comment: I don't know what closures have in common with setTimeout, but the rest is the very best solution. +1

Comment: +1 for the working solution. But its a bit complicated for me. So il stick with an easier one.

Comment: @MarsOne Yeah the link is fixed now. I strongly advise you to use this approach over the other one.

Comment: The fucntion name that you gave me looked scary. Anyways, you are right, i will use this. But im really sorry. I wouldnt like to change my marking of solution. Hope you understand'

Comment: @MarsOne It's really important that you understand these concepts in JS. Ask me any question ;) The function name `incMtrAsync` could have been anything you like, here it stands for `incrementMeterAsynchronously`.

Comment: @plalx beatiful solution, +1 for this.

Answer (score 5):

Nobody used setInterval, so here's my solution ( http://jsfiddle.net/Qh6gb/4/) :

```
var a = document.getElementById("mtr1");
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    console.log(i);
    a.value = ++i;
    if (i == 10) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 250);
```

Comment: I like this approach. Seems simple enough

Comment: Yep, that's another clean way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you describe happens before the asyncronous call to `setTimeout` in your original version sees a value of `10` for `i` because that is its value at the moment the callback is executed.

So, this is a problem with the scope of the closure, to make it work you should make it like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    var a = document.getElementById("mtr1");
    (function (i, a) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          console.log(i);
          a.value = i;
        }, 250);
    })(i, a);
}
```

also, since `a` is always the same, this should be better:

```
var a = document.getElementById("mtr1");
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          console.log(i);
          a.value = i;
        }, 250);
    })(i);
}
```

If then you want to see the counter "ticking up", this will make it visible:

```
var a = document.getElementById("mtr1");
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          console.log(i);
          a.value = i;
        }, 1000 * i);
    })(i);
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/LDt4d/

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you called setTimeout, which is "asynchronous". So setTimeout is called 10times but after whole loop is done then it is executed. Therefore, i = 10 in each call...

http://jsfiddle.net/Qh6gb/9/

there is the solution:

```
var i = 1,
    meter = document.getElementById("mtr1");

function increase() {
    meter.value = i++;
    console.log(i);
    if(i<=10) {
        setTimeout(increase, 250);
    }
}

setTimeout(increase, 250);
```

Comment: yeah I don't understand too... my first explain was correct, just a little short...

Comment: Only thing I can think is the use of the word asynchronous, javascript is never asynchronous, even when it may appear it is running in this manner. It uses a deferred model rather than multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

you can use   `timeout` jquery plugin:. It is **easier**

However you should calculate your timeout ,

For you ,`timeout=250*max=250*10=2500`

So

```
$('meter').timeout(2500);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/Qh6gb/14/)

Answer (score 0):

Run for loop inside the function instead of declaring a closure in every step of the loop.

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/Qh6gb/3/

```
var a = document.getElementById("mtr1");
setTimeout(function () {      
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        a.value = i;
    }
}, 250);
```

Comment: This is what you want.

Comment: he wants each iteration to be executed 250 ms apart i beleive

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand right. Please try and tell me if you got solution.

```
var count = 0;
function increment(){
    document.getElementById("meter").value = count; 
    count++; 
    if(count ==10) 
        count=0;
}
setInterval(increment, 250);
```

Please check with [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LyCHT/)

Answer (score -1):

You're creating multiple functions that are all being set off at the same time. 
Multiply the timer by i for correct delay.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
var a = document.getElementById("mtr1");
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(i);
    a.value = i;
}, 250 * i);
}
```